# Wordpress Linux file permissions and group

Tags: linux, wordpress, file, permissions

I have a Linux server (Debian 7) with lots of users who needs Wordpress. When I create the users what group should they be in? Today I assign them to `www-data`.
Then they download Wordpress by SFTP and runs the installation.

Which file permissions and user/group should their files have, specially `wp-config.php`?

Now, users can peek in eachothers `wp-config.php` from the terminal and read the password. Not very good.

Since the users aren't root they cant change file permissions/owner of `wp-config.php` which would solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this script by Mike Conigliaro for  for setting permissions correctly on all wordpress files.

```
WP_OWNER=changeme # <-- wordpress owner
WP_GROUP=changeme # <-- wordpress group
WP_ROOT=/home/changeme # <-- wordpress root directory
WS_GROUP=changeme # <-- webserver group

# reset to safe defaults
find ${WP_ROOT} -exec chown ${WP_OWNER}:${WP_GROUP} {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT} -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT} -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

# allow wordpress to manage wp-config.php (but prevent world access)
chgrp ${WS_GROUP} ${WP_ROOT}/wp-config.php
chmod 660 ${WP_ROOT}/wp-config.php

# allow wordpress to manage .htaccess
touch ${WP_ROOT}/.htaccess
chgrp ${WS_GROUP} ${WP_ROOT}/.htaccess
chmod 664 ${WP_ROOT}/.htaccess

# allow wordpress to manage wp-content
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -exec chgrp ${WS_GROUP} {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Comment: Nice if you had the decency to credit the author. It was only a couple of extra comment lines? Original here: http://www.conigliaro.org/2010/05/06/script-to-configure-proper-wordpress-permissions/

Comment: Ive had that script for years and use it daily.. no rip of intended sir just quickly sharing what i had.

Comment: Share away! I don't mind. 

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:
Create users in a group "`users`". Create a script in `/etc/cron.hourly` that fixes permissions on all wp-config.php-files like this:

```
for f in locate wp-config.php
do
    chgrp www-data $f
    chmod 640 $f
done
```

Works like a charm.